# Regex select between brackets if given word is found

Tags: regex

I need to work out a regex that can select text surrounded by square brackets given that a particular word is present between the brackets.

I've gotten pretty close with this rule:

```
/\[(.*?)ermittelbar(.*?)\]/gi
```

(the word I'm currently targeting is "ermittelbar")

Problem is, if I test it on regexr.com for example I see that if I place any opening brackets before the text I wish to match, the selection is extended to include that opening bracket and anything in between.

So:

```
[created ermittelbar]
```

Is matched. But so is:

```
[ ]was [created ermittelbar]
```

Closing or opening brackets after my initial selection are not included unless the target word is included.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Exclude the brackets, [`/\[([^\][]*?)ermittelbar([^\][]*)\]/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/j3h3fw/2).

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. Was looking at some old answers suggesting the same, but could not work out how to integrate it.

Comment: I wonder if the closing bracket needs to be excluded [`\[[^[]*?ermittelbar[^[]*]`](https://regex101.com/r/LwG3xQ/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble: no but you avoid useless backtracking between the closing bracket and the next opening bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.*` pattern use `[^\][]` to match any char excluding brackets:

```
/\[([^\][]*?)ermittelbar([^\][]*)\]/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j3h3fw/2).

**Details**

- `\[` - `[` char
- `([^\][]*?)` - Group 1: any char other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `ermittelbar` - a literal substring
- `([^\][]*)` - Group 2: any char other than `[` and `]`, as many as possible
- `\]` - `]` char.